# slow wired network

Tags: networking, internet

I have installed elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir with Linux 5.15.0-56-generic kernel.
Yesterday my network company switched me from a 10mbps to a 100mbps optical fiber connection witch a new modem.
I have installed a Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 Gigabit ethernet controller on my old AsRock H61M/U3S3.
If I connect directly to modem, wired connection does not works.
I have to use a ethernet switch with a very slow connection (my brother with an Ubuntu 22.04 goes around 300mbps; I am stuck at 10mbps).
Before buying a new ethernet card and a new switch, Is there somebody that had same issues and can help me?
Thanks, Rino.

Comment: Did you eliminate the possibility of bad cables?

Comment: yes; two PCs, same cable, different velocity.

Comment: Good, you can now try disabling IPv6 temporarly: `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` and replug the eth cable.